# Is there a way to achieve below using pivot or something else in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to achieve below using pivot in T-SQL:

| brand a | revenue | brand b | revenue` | brand c | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| branch 1 | 20,000 | branch 6 | 9000 | branch 9 | 11000 |
| branch 3 | 15000 | branch 5 | 2000 | branch 6 | 8000 |
| branch 9 | 10000 | branch 10 | 1500 | branch 4 | 5000 |

However I'm getting this result:

| brand a | brand b | brand c | branch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20000 | null | null | branch 1 |
| 15000 | null | null | branch 3 |
| 10000 | null | 11000 | branch 9 |
| null | 9000 | 8000 | branch 6 |
| null | 2000 | null | branch 5 |
| null | 1500 | null | branch 10 |

I've used this query

```
select
    brand a, 
    brand b,
    brand c,
    Branch
from
    (select
         r.Branch,
         r.Revenue,
         r.brand
     from 
         (--data from sales table
          select 
              branch, sum(revenue) Revenue, p.brand, 
              Row_number() over (partition by (p.brand) order by sum(revenue) desc) [rank] 
          from sales s
          join Product p on s.prodid = p.prodid
          join branch b on s.Branch = b.branch
          where p.brand in ('brand a', ' brand b', ' brand c')
            and time between @startdate and @enddate
          group by branch, p.brand) r
     where 
         r.rank <= 3) p1
pivot
    (max(revenue)
         for brand in (`brand a`, `brand b`, `brand c`)
    ) piv
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also show sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when brand = 'brand a' then branch end) as branch_a,
       sum(case when brand = 'brand a' then revenue end) as revenue_a,
       max(case when brand = 'brand b' then branch end) as branch_b,
       sum(case when brand = 'brand b' then revenue end) as revenue_b,
       max(case when brand = 'brand c' then branch end) as branch_c,
       sum(case when brand = 'brand c' then revenue end) as revenue_c
from (select b.branch, sum(revenue) as Revenue, p.brand, 
             row_number() over (partition by p.brand order by 
      sum(revenue) desc) as seqnum
      from sales s join
           Product p
           on s.prodid = p.prodid join
           branch b
           on s.Branch = b.branch
      where p.brand in ('brand a',' brand b',' brand c') and
            time between @startdate and @enddate
      group by branch, p.brand
     ) pb
group by seqnum;
```

Comment: I'd like to view top 3 by revenue for each brand. I forgot to add in my question. Sorry!

Comment: @pz1 . . . You can add `where seqnum <= 3` to the outer query.

Comment: Gordon, you know everything in the SQL universe!